# What went wrong in this trivial merge?

Tags: mercurial

**Edit**: This certainly isn't good practice on stackoverflow and I sincerely apologize, but as it seems I was very unclear about the exact steps I was doing, causing confusion. Therefore I decided to rewrite the post and make it more clear which exact commands I was running and in what order to reproduce my experience.

Because I had to deal with bogus merges in Mercurial before, I did a little experiment:

```
cd example
hg init
```

create `example.dart`

```
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

```
hg add .\example.dart
hg commit -m "bogus add()"
hg branch other
```

add to `example.dart`:

```
num sub(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

```
hg commit -m "correct sub()"
hg update default
hg commit -m "fix add()"

(note by me: Mercurial messes up some characters)
hg log -G
@  ─nderung:        2:19a3c127981b
|  Marke:           tip
|  Vorgõnger:       0:ac1d30ac2dda
|  Nutzer:          Marvin
|  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:31:24 2019 +0200
|  Zusammenfassung: fix add()
|
| o  ─nderung:        1:645416c58a38
|/   Zweig:           other
|    Nutzer:          Marvin
|    Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:23:40 2019 +0200
|    Zusammenfassung: correct sub()
|
o  ─nderung:        0:ac1d30ac2dda
   Nutzer:          Marvin
   Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:19:47 2019 +0200
   Zusammenfassung: bogus add()

hg update other
hg graft 19a3c127981b

hg log -G
@  ─nderung:        3:567c99a23b17
|  Zweig:           other
|  Marke:           tip
|  Vorgõnger:       1:645416c58a38
|  Nutzer:          Marvin
|  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:31:24 2019 +0200
|  Zusammenfassung: fix add()
|
| o  ─nderung:        2:19a3c127981b
| |  Vorgõnger:       0:ac1d30ac2dda
| |  Nutzer:          Marvin
| |  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:31:24 2019 +0200
| |  Zusammenfassung: fix add()
| |
o |  ─nderung:        1:645416c58a38
|/   Zweig:           other
|    Nutzer:          Marvin
|    Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:23:40 2019 +0200
|    Zusammenfassung: correct sub()
|
o  ─nderung:        0:ac1d30ac2dda
   Nutzer:          Marvin
   Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:19:47 2019 +0200
   Zusammenfassung: bogus add()
```

This produces the expected result in `example.dart`:

```
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a + b;
}

num sub(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

```
hg update default
hg merge other
hg commit -m "merge with other"

hg log -G
@    ─nderung:        4:a76695f39931
|\   Marke:           tip
| |  Vorgõnger:       2:19a3c127981b
| |  Vorgõnger:       3:567c99a23b17
| |  Nutzer:          Marvin
| |  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:37:18 2019 +0200
| |  Zusammenfassung: merge with other
| |
| o  ─nderung:        3:567c99a23b17
| |  Zweig:           other
| |  Vorgõnger:       1:645416c58a38
| |  Nutzer:          Marvin
| |  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:31:24 2019 +0200
| |  Zusammenfassung: fix add()
| |
o |  ─nderung:        2:19a3c127981b
| |  Vorgõnger:       0:ac1d30ac2dda
| |  Nutzer:          Marvin
| |  Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:31:24 2019 +0200
| |  Zusammenfassung: fix add()
| |
| o  ─nderung:        1:645416c58a38
|/   Zweig:           other
|    Nutzer:          Marvin
|    Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:23:40 2019 +0200
|    Zusammenfassung: correct sub()
|
o  ─nderung:        0:ac1d30ac2dda
   Nutzer:          Marvin
   Datum:           Mon Jul 01 19:19:47 2019 +0200
   Zusammenfassung: bogus add()
```

The history now looks like expected. However, the merge result does not:

```
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a + b;
}

num sub(num a, num b) {
}
```

Interestingly the merge algorithm cleanly cuts out the body of `sub()` while not producing any conflicts.

The experiment was done on a Windows 10 machine with a freshly installed Mercurial 4.9.1. The only installed diff-tool is KDiff3 which comes with Mercurial and TortoiseHg (which I didn't use). Standard settings weren't changed and no plugins were activated.

Maybe this is just some weird corner case, though I would be very interested in what causes it. I would be very happy for any insight you could give. Bogus merges like this cause enormous headaches, hence I think this is relevant.

Comment: Since @torek 's experiment didn't reproduce the problem, maybe there is a local difference. What version of HG are you using? And is there anything in your .hgrc which pertains to merge settings? (Maybe add your hgrc here). I wonder if a third-party merge tool is doing something.

Comment: Indeed, reading @torek's answer makes me aware that I should have been more explicit about the actual commands I was running. His answer makes perfect sense, but these weren't the steps I took.

And just to be clear: This might be just nitpicking about some rare corner case. It would nonetheless be interesting to understand it.

Comment: I expect *something wrong* with your selected mergetool anyway: I repeated again step-by-step in CLI your process and got (as expected) conflict on merge

`>hg merge other`
`merging example.dart`
`running merge tool p4merge for file example.dart`

Comment: Found possible source, added details to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercurial (TortoiseHG) 4.9.1, the same result as @torek wrote

THG's version of failed merge

```
% hg merge --config=ui.merge=:merge --verbose 3
resolving manifests
merging functions.c
warning: conflicts while merging functions.c! (edit, then use 'hg resolve --mark')
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg merge --abort' to abandon
```

and (expected) state of the file in the middle of process (immediately after the above merge)

```
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a + b;
<<<<<<< working copy
=======
}

num sub(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
>>>>>>> merge rev
}
```

**Addition**

This merge **can't be non-conflicting merge** for *usual* merge-tools (GUI presentation will be better here)

[image: Merging]

because grey string /(1) om screenshot/ in merge-result **IS** conflicted area, which (conflict) *have to be resolved* in any way. But, if we supposing after observing "other" file (right-side of merge-panel, (2) area on screenshot) and your described result

```
num sub(num a, num b) {
}
```

that your default merge-tool can be tool, which dictate *own policy*, not *resolving*, it can be answer on question "Why it happened".

Slightly more deep: if your default merge-tool is somehow "internal:other", then

- Green Section (2) from "other side" have to appear in merge-result (as requested by selecting mergetool)
- Conflict-area (1) just ignored
- Closing bracket } (3) is common hunk for both sides of merge and transferred to merge-result

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your experience.  Here is my attempt:

```
$ mkdir hg
$ cd hg
$ hg init
$ cat > exp.lang << 'end'
> num add(num a, num b) {
>   return a - b;
> }
> end
$ hg add exp.lang
$ hg commit -m initial
$ hg branch other
marked working directory as branch other
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
$ cat >> exp.lang << 'end'
> 
> num sub(num a, num b) {
>   return a - b;
> }
> end
$ hg commit -m 'add sub()'
$ hg checkout default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ ed exp.lang
42
2
  return a - b;
s/-/+/
w
42
q
$ hg commit -m 'fix bug'
```

As far as I can tell, this is what you said you did: fix the bug on the default branch.  Let's graft the fix and see if it looks right:

```
$ hg checkout other
$ hg graft -r 2
grafting 2:2670b3299c96 "fix bug" (tip)
merging exp.lang
$ hg lga                 # lga is a graphical log alias
@  3:811f4d1a7dc4:draft  other tip Chris Torek
|  fix bug (54 seconds ago)
|
| o  2:2670b3299c96:draft  Chris Torek
| |  fix bug (54 seconds ago)
| |
o |  1:a780b1c8c579:draft  other Chris Torek
|/   add sub() (112 seconds ago)
|
o  0:b085834fc520:draft  Chris Torek
   initial (3 minutes ago)

$ cat exp.lang
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a + b;
}

num sub(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

So far, so good - as far as I can tell, I have reproduced your setup.  Now:

```
$ hg checkout default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ hg merge other
warning: conflicts while merging exp.lang! (edit, then use 'hg resolve --mark')
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg merge --abort' to abandon
```

The merge failed because Mercurial needs human help.  Here's what Mercurial saw:

```
$ cat exp.lang
num add(num a, num b) {
<<<<<<< working copy
  return a + b;
||||||| base
  return a - b;
=======
  return a + b;
}

num sub(num a, num b) {
  return a - b;
>>>>>>> merge rev
}
```

The base copy of the file, from revision 0, has the bug: `add` returns `a - b`.  The tip of the current (default) branch, version 2, looks like this:

```
$ hg abort
aborting the merge, updating back to 2670b3299c96
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cat exp.lang
num add(num a, num b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

which is what we should expect: the bug is fixed.  The revision we're merging in has the same one-line fix, *but* also inserts all this other stuff—four extra lines—before the final close brace.  Which one should the VCS use, the one line fix or the five line fix?  It doesn't know, so it stops to get help.

Comment: I am very sorry to have caused confusion. I tried to make my steps clearer in the updated question. Doing the steps you did, I get the same result. However, I did it a little bit different.